# C# WPF Set ScrollViewer vertical offset at item position

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scrollviewer

I'm using a `ScrollViewer` to scroll an `ItemsControl` with a variable number of `TextBox`.

```html
<ScrollViewer extension:ScrollViewerExtension.ScrollOffset="{Binding TotalSearchOccurence}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
   <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewSource}}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
          <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
      </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <controls:HighlightTextBlock IsHighlightEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.SearchBarModel.IsVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor ,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" LineHightlights="{Binding Path=LineHightlights}" Text="{Binding Path=Content, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="{Binding Path=Color, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="14" SelectedHighlightIndex="{Binding SelectedHighlightIndex}"/>                                      
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

I want to set the vertical offset of my `ScrollViewer` at a specific line item position so that this item is at the top of my screen (if this item is not in the lasts positions of my `ItemControl`).

The different information I have is the total number of items in my `ItemControl` and the maximum scrollable offset of my `ScrollViewer`.

How can I manage to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by _the maximum scrollable offset_ and why do you compare it with _the total number of items in my ItemControl_?

Comment: The maximum scrollable offset is obtained with the ScrollableHeight propriety in the ScrollViewer class. It represent the vertical size of the content element that can be scrolled. I think this is useful for the result in association with the total number of elements to get the right position of an item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a call to `BringToView()` on your UIElement.

For exemple, if you have a `TextBlock` contained inside your items list of
an `ItemsControl` encapsulated in a `ScrollViewer`, you can just do `TextBlock.BringIntoView()`.